# Simplify boolean logic

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

Simple question, can the following logic

```
A && !(A && B)
```

be simplified into this?

```
A && !B
```

If not can it be simplified at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: yes. You can check this with a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table):

```
A  B  X
-  -  -
0  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  1
1  1  0
```

i.e. X is true only when A is true and B is false.

You can also prove this algebraically if you really want to:

```
  A && !(A && B)

= A && (!A || !B)           ; de Morgan

= (A && !A) || (A && !B)

= 0 || (A && !B)            ; X && !X is always FALSE

= A && !B
```

Comment: I knew it, I have the exact same truth tables scribbled down in front of me, but for some reason it still didn't seem right! Always helpful to get a second opinion. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the algebra solution too. Algebra has always made more sense to me than truth tables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it most definitely can: if `A` is false then the expression is false, and if `A` is true, then `A` *is* true and the expression is true iff `B` is false.